# Htaccess to change URL displayed in browser

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

I am trying to prevent xyz.com from appearing in the browser address bar but still direct abc.com traffic to the xyz.com site.  I was expecting that to happen once I removed "R" from the [QSA, L]. However there doesn't appear to be any change.  Is there a different HTTP header or connection variable that I should be using?

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
rewriterule ^ http://xyz.com/?snack [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a big confusion in people's mind that by removing `R` flag URL will never change and it will remain an internal (silent) forward.

Fact is that if your changing domain names in target URL (by using `http://` etc) then URL **will change** and it will be an `external redirect`.

**No URL change  (Internal Rewrite):**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ /?snack [QSA,L]
```

**URL will change (External Redirect):**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ ttp://xyz.com/?snack [QSA,L]
```

**PS:** Only way to avoid URL changing when going to a different domain is by using `mod_proxy` which is considered somewhat a *security risk*.

Comment: Would it make a difference that abc.com is just an alias? It is just a domain hosted on the same server as xyz.com.

Comment: No that won't make any difference to above rules. You can of course remove `RewriteCond` if you want to apply above rules for `http://xyz.com/foo` also.